# Error in build apk

Tags: android, android-studio

my error message is:

```
//Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/annotations/Beta;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)//
```

please help me to fix this
my build.gradle

```
//dependencies {
compile project(':appRater')
compile project(':circularImageView')
compile project(':facebookSDK')
compile project(':paperSlidingTab')
compile project(':library')
compile project(':urlImageViewHelper')
compile project(':pullToRefreshLi')
compile project(':libraries:SlidingMenu:library')
compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.5.jar')
compile files('libs/json-org.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1-with-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/WebSocket.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile files('libs/applause-sdk-library-2.0.0.jar')
compile 'org.droidparts:droidparts:1.+'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.+'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android2:1.+'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.+'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android2:1.+'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.+'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.+'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.+'
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.+'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 17
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (System.getenv("GRADLE_KEYSTORE")) {
            storeFile = file(System.getenv("GRADLE_KEYSTORE"))
            storePassword = System.getenv("GRADLE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias = System.getenv("GRADLE_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword = System.getenv("GRADLE_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
    }
}

buildTypes.debug {
    ext.enableCrashlytics = false
}

buildTypes.release {
    debuggable false
    zipAlignEnabled true
    minifyEnabled false
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
}
```

Comment: In your dependencies you are using different version of the same class. Check your jars first of all.

Answer (score 1):

This appear when we use same library with 2 or more versions in one project. So try to find the versions of libraries in your app especially support-v4 library

```
   android {
      compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

        defaultConfig {
            ...
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19
            ...

            // Enabling multidex support.
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    }
```

You can use below code too , This work in mine case

```
 dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

Comment: i try first answer not working, error become many..i try second answer

Answer (score 0):

```
defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
     targetSdkVersion 22

     // Enabling multidex support.
     multiDexEnabled true
 }
```

or you can do by make an Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { .. }
```

or

```
override 
attachBaseContext method and call MultiDex.install().
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
super.attachBaseContext(base);
MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Otherwise (if your application does not have custom Application implementation), declare MultiDexApplication as application implementation in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<application
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
.. >
..
</application>
```

Comment: All answer not working..anyone please can help me to fix this error

Comment: @dany i provide another ways also which can help you. try once and let me know

Comment: its working but show this error : Error:Execution failed for task ':socialapp:packageAllReleaseClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/collect/package-info.class

Comment: some dependency is duplicate. remove unnessasry dependancy and check